# Are there additional logs available for Web API applications on AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We deployed a .NET application on Amazon EC2, which uses [ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api).
It has a connection to a RDS database.

The problem is, that when we try to get a model from the server
(for example: `GET /Users/1`) we get an `Internal Server Error`.

I want to find out what the problem is, but the log file under Logs / Snapshot logs said nothing about the error.

Are there any other log files in EC2? Or how can I find out what is the problem inside the application?

Comment: I would recommend SSHing into your EC2 and checking the log files there. By default the beanstalk logs feature on the UI only picks up preset logs.

Comment: Thank you! If you answer, i will accept it.